# Javascript Controller capitalize and remove accents

Tags: regular-expressions

I use in a javascript controller the function for every variable string str that i have in a custom lightning component

```
str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toUpperCase().trim()
```

in order to capitalize the letters and remove accents. However i need to keep some accents related to greek letters, which have to to with the symbols ϊ, ϋ, Ϊ, Ϋ. Is there any easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider looping over each character in the string and writing some helper function that checks if the letter is in an 'accepted character's array, and replaces it (with nothing, as you are doing now, or with the 'simplified' letter) when it is not. You may need to store the specific unicode value for these 'accepted' letters (“ϊ” = U+03CA, others can be found at https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, Dan. So, is there a way i could say that i want range from u0300 until U+0307 and then range:  U+0309 - U+036F. So that character table U+0308 remains! I just don't know the syntax and if it is applicable.

Comment: Great question, I believe what you're looking for is a 'negative lookahead' that says 'if character is in some list, but not in this list'. Example: `(?![\u0308])[\u0300-\u036f]`

Comment: Thanks! Finally i did it with helper function and changing the characters cause i could not make it work. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!